# display variable object name ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, object

I have 2 previously defined strings :

table_string that holds the table name and field_string that holds the field name in this table , these 2 strings are variables and change depending on the previous page where they are coming

for example in a specified page i will press on a link that will redirect me to this page with `table_string=user and field_string=fullname` 
I should here access the attribute @user.fullname 
I tried to concatenate table_string + "." + field_string`in another string let's say x and then display`
<%= @x %>`as if im typing`@user.fullname` but this does not work

How can I display this variable field knowing that the table name will also changes ???

Comment: Check out the `send` method: http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send . As for the object instantiation, I don't think it's possible to do it the way you propose.

Comment: this is not useful because i need the object name (table name ) to be variable also .

Comment: actually it is impossible to do that in the way i proposed

Comment: well now i fixed the table name , but when trying to write @student.send("name") it does not work , is there any function other than send

Answer (score 1):

Try the 'instance_variable_get' method.

```
table_name = 'user'
column_name = 'name'
instance_variable_get("@#{table_name}").send(column_name)
```

or just

```
instance_variable_get("@#{table_name}")[column_name]
```